# how can format column name in case when in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `created_at` column(date type) I need to format it with just `year and month` before case when. I try this query but it gives `0` and I have users in my table!

I'm using MySQL:

```
select 
  count(case when DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%c') = 2022-1 then 1 end)
  as one from `users` limit 1
```

Comment: `2022-1` is arithmetic expression which is eqial to 2021. Where are quotes?

Comment: @Akina How stupid Am I broo!! :(

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT(1) AS one FROM users WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31 23:59:59'`. If the index by `created_at` exists then the query can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a string instead of the arithmetic expresseion:

```
select 
  count(case when DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%c') = '2022-1' then 1 end)
  as one from `users` limit 1
```

Your expression is the same as

```
select 
  count(case when DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%c') = 2021 then 1 end)
  as one from `users` limit 1
```